# OWIN Pipeline Injection causing the Callback Failure With 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: owin, openid-connect

I'm using Owin OpenIdConnect authentication for communicating Office365 API's.
For this I'm injecting my authentication flow in Owin StartUp class.

```
private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = Office365SettingsHelper.ClientId,
            Authority = Office365SettingsHelper.Authority,
            TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false
            },
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                {
                    var code = context.Code;
                    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(Office365SettingsHelper.ClientId, Office365SettingsHelper.AppKey);
                    string tenantID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
                    string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                    var userObjectId = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
                    var email = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Name;
                    Office365TokenCache cacheObject = new Office365TokenCache(signedInUserID);
                    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("{0}/{1}", Office365SettingsHelper.AuthorizationUri, tenantID), cacheObject);
                    AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, Office365SettingsHelper.AADGraphResourceId);

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                {
                    context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = Office365SettingsHelper.RedirectUri; ;
                    context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = Office365SettingsHelper.RedirectUri;
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                {
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

I'm using this to register the OpenIdConnect flow.
When I'm using that flow, the callback's fails with 500 Internal Server Error.

```
Callback Request Header
POST http://localhost:53508/SignIn.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:53508
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 612
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: http://localhost:53508
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like    Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:53508/SignIn.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: TimezoneID=MTIyMDQ5;
```

Callback Response Header

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 31 Mar 2015 13:05:11 GMT
```

Stack Trace

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: parameter]
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.AuthenticationProtocolMessage.SetParameter(String parameter, String value) +103
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnectMessage..ctor(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +274
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__1a.MoveNext() +1606
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<BaseInitializeAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +810
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +427
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +287
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +937
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +287
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext() +272
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +22
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.Infrastructure.ErrorState.Rethrow() +33
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +150
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +42
System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +415
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34212
```

Looks like **app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication** is causing the problem,
Because when I'm commenting this step, I'm not getting this issue.

If anything else is required, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, there are a lot of possibilities. I suspect the issue is in the AuthorizationCodeNotifications.
Are you able to attach a debugger or generate logs?

Comment: Hi Brent,
I've updated the question with stack trace. Let me know if you still needed anything else.

Comment: I think I may see the issue.

Comment: OIDCMessage ctor checks parameter != null before calling SetParameter while the base checks string.IsNullOrEmpty. What IdentityProvider are you using?  I don't see a workaround I may need to fix this.

Comment: Hi @Brent, We are using ConfigureAuth Method For setting the flow..
Question is updated with the Full Method we are using. Not sure where to look for IdentityProvider. FYI I'm not setting any ClaimsIdentity for IdentityProvider. May be it is taking the default value for IdentityProvider.

Comment: @Shekhar I would like to push a fix based on above and have you try it out.

Comment: Thanks @Brent, please do the needful at your end & I'll be happy to work with your fix.

Comment: Hi @Brent, We are still stuck here. Do we have any update on this ?

Comment: We pushed out the fix in our nightlies: https://www.myget.org/gallery/azureadwebstacknightly

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extenstions and System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt is what you want.